# group p:picklist elements like in html <optgroup> tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces, picklist

I'm using the `p:pickList` component from primefaces, as shown:
[image]

This is my code:

```
    <p:pickList id="cityPicklist" rendered="true" var="city"
                    style="font-size: 11px" effect="bounce" itemValue="#{city}"
                    converter="cityConverter" itemLabel="#{city}"
                    showSourceControls="true" showTargetControls="true"
                    showCheckbox="false" responsive="true" showSourceFilter="true"
                    showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                    value="#{myView.cities}">

        
                    <p:column style="width:100%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{city.name}" />
                    </p:column>

                </p:pickList>
```

What i'm trying to achieve is the following result:

[image]

But the code generated from primefaces renders a UL tag with individual LI for each city from `myView.cities`.

```
<div class="ui-picklist-list-wrapper">

<ul class="ui-widget-content ui-picklist-list ui-picklist-source ui-corner-all 
    ui-sortable" role="menu" tabindex="0">

<li class="ui-picklist-item ui-corner-all ui-sortable-handle" 
    data-item-value="San Francisco" data-item-label="Europe" 
    role="menuitem" style="
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 1;"> Europe</li>

<li class="ui-picklist-item ui-corner-all ui-sortable-handle" data-item-value="London" 
    data-item-label="London" role="menuitem" style="
    margin-left: 20px;
">London</li>

<li class="ui-picklist-item ui-corner-all ui-sortable-handle" data-item-value="Paris" 
    data-item-label="Paris" role="menuitem" style="
    margin-left: 20px;

...
```

Is there any way to group the elements within the picklist using primefaces library? or will i have to rewrite this component in order to achieve such result?

Comment: I don't think grouping is currently possible with the PickList.  I think you would have to request that enhancement on the GitHub page: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues, provide a patch, or you could sponsor it via Primefaces PRO paid request and PrimeTek will implement it for you.